# Prettify JSON file in ansible

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

Say I have a JSON file from a template

```
- name: consul config file
  template: >
    src={{ consul_config_template }}
    dest={{ consul_config_file }}
    owner={{ consul_user }}
    group={{ consul_group }}
    mode=0755
```

How can I prettify the JSON file in order to remove extra spaces and newlines? Is there any ansible module I can call after `template`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with one shot:

```
- copy:
    content: "{{ item | to_nice_json }}"
    dest: "{{ consul_config_file }}"
    owner: "{{ consul_user }}"
    group: "{{ consul_group }}"
    mode: 0755
  with_template: "{{ consul_config_template }}"
```